# get min and max of dates in an object

Tags: javascript

I'm given this object

`{"2017-1-1":true,"2017-1-2":true,"2017-1-3":true}`, how can I get the min date and max date? I need the range too. What I did was

```
temp = Object.keys(obj[0]).split('-')[2]
const minDate = Math.min(...temp);
const maxDate = Math.min(...temp);
//and then concat year and month to rebuild the date format
```

Which I think is bad code. Any better alternative?

Comment: Life would be much easier if you held the dates in the format `"yyyy-mm-dd"`.

Comment: What is `obj`? What do you expect `obj[0]` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
const obj = { 
  "2017-1-1":true,
  "2017-1-2":true,
  "2017-1-3":true 
};

/* we get the time in ms here, so we can use it to compare */
const dates = Object.keys(obj).map(date => new Date(date).getTime());

/* we could use one loop and check each value to 
make this a little bit more performant but I didn't find it relevant here */
const minDate = new Date(Math.min(...dates));
const maxDate = new Date(Math.max(...dates));
```

Take a look to the [Date docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and the [Array.map function docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Create DateTime objects that represent the first and last dates in a range.

```
DateTime projectStart = new DateTime(2001, 2, 13);  
DateTime projectEnd = new DateTime(2001, 2, 28);
```

Set the SelectionRange property.

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionRange = new SelectionRange(projectStart, projectEnd);
```

–or–

Set the SelectionStart and SelectionEnd properties.

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionStart = projectStart;  
monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = projectEnd;
```

Comment: what is SelectionRange??

Comment: DateTime projectStart = new DateTime(2001, 2, 13);  
DateTime projectEnd = new DateTime(2001, 2, 28);